On-chain vs Off-chain: Where should data querying and pagination be handled for large datasets?
Let's say there was smart contract and dApp to manage books. The scenario is dApp need to perform a query and pagination then use the result to display to the end user. My concern is the stored books data is growing and at certain point it probably get out of gas limit.
My question:

Should I handle pagination and querying within the smart contract (as shown), or is it better to handle these operations off-chain to avoid gas limit issues?
If handling it on-chain is feasible, what are the best practices to ensure that the contract remains efficient as the dataset grows?

Below is simplified version of contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.9;

contract BookStore {
    struct Book {
        string title;
        string author;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 stock;
    }

    uint256 public bookCount;
    mapping(uint256 id => Book detail) public books;

    event BookAdded(uint256 id, string title, string author, uint256 price, uint256 stock);
    event BookUpdated(uint256 id, string title, string author, uint256 price, uint256 stock);

    function addBook(
        uint256 _id,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _author,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _stock
    ) external {
        // Add a new book
    }

    function updateBook(
        uint256 _id,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _author,
        uint256 _price,
        uint256 _stock
    ) external {
        // Update an existing book
    }

    function queryBook(uint256 _page, uint256 _size, string memory _title) external view returns (Book[] memory) {
        // Query books by title
    }

    function queryBook(
        uint256 _page,
        uint256 _size,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _author
    ) external view returns (Book[] memory) {
        // Query books by title and author
    }
}



Don't store all book information directly on the blockchain. Instead, save important details like who owns the book and its purchase history on the blockchain. Store the rest of the book information (like title, Author) off the blockchain. When someone wants to find a book, search for it using the information on the blockchain and then fetch the full details from off-chain storage. This will save money and make the system faster.


Should I handle pagination and querying within the smart contract (as shown), or is it better to handle these operations off-chain to avoid gas limit issues?

Gas issues are no issue as long as the caller can control the query page size.
No reason to handle off chain.
